# Number of possible rectangles from at most N identical squares

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I was looking to find the number of distinct rectangles possible from at most $N$ identical squares. (Two rectangles are distinct if one cannot be rotated to obtain another)

e.g for $N = 6$ , $8$ rectangles are possible

[image]

On searching from Google, I came across a formula

number of rectangles = $\lfloor 3n/2\rfloor-1$ for  ($n>1$).

Can anyone explain how he arrived at that formula??

Comment: It looks too simple to hold for all $n \gt 1$.  Where did you find this formula?  I think it only counts the $1\times m$ and $2\times m$ rectangles, so it should break down at $N=9$.

Answer (score 2):

This formula is wrong for $N=1$, since one square allows one rectangle but $\lfloor 3/2 \rfloor - 1 = 0$.

However thereafter it counts the number of rectangles with at most two rows, ie. rectangles of the form $1\times m$ or $2\times m$.  One can reason this by considering the number of $1\times m$ rectangles is $N$, taking $m = 1,\ldots,N$, and the number of $2\times m$ rectangles is $\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$, similarly for $m = 1,\ldots,\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$.  Since $1\times 2$ rectangle gets counted twice, subtract $1$ from combining this terms:

$$ N + \lfloor N/2 \rfloor - 1 = \lfloor 3N/2 \rfloor - 1 $$

But the formula won't account for $3\times m$ rectangles with $m \ge 3$, so it doesn't truly tell the number of rectangles possible for up to $N$ squares when $N \ge 9$.  The formula gives $12$ but this doesn't account for $3\times 3$ rectangle, so that the right answer would be $13$ possibilities.

Comment: So I take it, you are aiming for the formula $$R(N)=\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt N\rfloor}\left[\lfloor N/i\rfloor -(i-1)\right]$$ where for $1<N<9$ we have the special case of $$R(N)=N+\lfloor N/2\rfloor-1$$

Comment: @String: You are giving me too much credit!  The thought crossed my mind to work out the correct formula using inclusion/exclusion, but I was waiting to get some feedback from the OP before sweating the details.  I really only wanted to flesh out the proposition that the given formula has shortcomings and can't be "arrived at" as a matter of proof.  See my earlier Comment on the Question.